# Capturing bash history of piped scripts from within Perl or Ruby?

Tags: ruby, perl, bash, pipe

If I run this command in bash shell:

```
script1 -i foo | script2 -i bar | script3 -i foobar
```

Is there a robust way to obtain that command as it would appear in bash_history from within script1-3?

As far as I can tell, getting the information from the .bash_history file is no-go since writing to that file is buffered and it thus may be out of sync.

Comment: Technically, there are three commands there, put together into a pipeline. Each script can recover its own command from argv, although only in the final processed form (that is, with variables expanded, words split, quotes removed, etc.) But there is no way to get the entire pipeline. And as you say, the history file is useless (not because writing is buffered so much as that writing is only done occasionally, although you can make history writing much more aggressive.)

Comment: Maybe there is a way to hook into the bash history buffer? Clearly the scripts needs to interact with the shell to get the information.

Comment: Hm, it is possible to set an environment variable to ensure flushing of the history buffer: `export PROMPT_COMMAND='history -a'`. Is it then possible to get the info from .bash_history?

Comment: You could try that, certainly. (But only in one shell at a time, unless you create a separate history file for every session.)

Comment: Hm, I really need this to work for multiple sessions. It is also possible to sync the history between sessions with: `export PROMPT_COMMAND='history -a; history -r'` - but I am concerned about race conditions.

Comment: Yes, you should be concerned about race conditions. I'd use a different history file for each session. You can use the variable $HISTFILE to set the history filename; export the variable so you scripts know which file to look in. Use something like ~/.history.$$ (which will add the pid to the filename) so that every session has a  separate file.

Answer (score 0):

You can attach a OS level tracer to your program and then look for `exec` system calls.

Those that go through a shell appear as `["sh", "-c", "$cmd"]`, `$cmd` is what you are looking for.

For instance, on Linux, using `strace`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my $parent = $$;
my $pid = fork;

unless ($pid) {
    defined $pid or die "fork failed: $!\n";
    open STDOUT, '>&STDERR'; # redirect stdout to stderr
    do { exec('strace',
              -p => $parent,
              -e => 'trace=clone,execve',
              -e => 'signal=none',
              -s => 32000,
              -b => 'execve',
              '-f', '-qq') };
    warn "exec failed: $!\n";
    POSIX::_exit(1);
}

sleep 2; # wait for strace to attach to me

system 'ls $HOME';
system 'echo /*';

END {
    kill TERM => $pid;
}
```